# API sha1 hash generation not matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, hash, sha1

I'm getting from Slideshare API explorer which is working:

```
64f43b4be73bc11a15142c1ef5dab1130c5064cb
```

From SHA1 hashing of below string

```
81LqkNkvy1391428643
```

But when I use in Rails:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("81LqkNkvy1391428643")
```

I get:

```
1ef520bb53227b9edf691d47da653f93d232e16e
```

I cannot figure out why this is not matching.

According to Slideshare API link

http://www.slideshare.net/developers/documentation

It clearly says

```
hash: Set this to the SHA1 hash of the concatenation of the shared secret and the 
timestamp (ts). i.e. SHA1 (sharedsecret + timestamp). The order of the terms 
in the concatenation is important.
```

I thought I followed the instructions correctly. I also tried decryption of above SHA1 strings but had no luck so far.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL parameter from the API explorer with shared secret set to `81LqkNkvy`:

```
...&hash=80c887e839d79dc38248ed4cda4b6ad401f57305&ts=1391434954
```

In Ruby:

```
sharedsecret = '81LqkNkvy'
timestamp = 1391434954

require 'digest'
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(sharedsecret + timestamp.to_s)
#=> "80c887e839d79dc38248ed4cda4b6ad401f57305"
```

And to get the *current* timestamp:

```
timestamp = Time.now.to_i
#=> 1391434369
```

Note that the hash changes every second.

Comment: Thanks but the shared secret is 81LqkNkvy and 1391428643 is from timestamp so I actually concatenated it after the secret

Comment: Updated the code, maybe your timestamp was different

Answer (score 0):

Tried time stamp in milliseconds ?

Comment: just multiply that by thousand. Did you use Time.now.to_i ?

Comment: Also according to their doc it says ts: Set this to the current time in Unix TimeStamp format, to the nearest second(?).

Comment: Then I dont think it requires those Zeros. Are you sure you took the time in utc ?